# Run docker inside LXC(LXD)

Tags: lxc, docker, lxd

I'm trying to install and run docker inside a LXC container (through LXD).

The container is created using `lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 democontainer`, and after I login and install docker (v1.12.3) it always fails in starting docker with the error:

```
FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: Devices cgroup isn't mounted
```

I have already tried to add this to the file `/var/lib/lxc/democontainer/config`

```
lxc.aa_profile = unconfined
lxc.cap.drop =
```

(and also `lxc.mount.auto = cgroup`) as stated [here](http://andrea.corbellini.name/2016/04/13/docker-swarm-inside-lxc/), but the result is the same. What may be the problem?

The host system is a Ubuntu 14.04.5 (kernel 4.2.0-42-generic) and the container an Ubuntu 16.04.1. Docker works fine in the host system (v 1.13.0)

Comment: Can I ask what's your use case? Docker and LXC are both providing containerization. Moreover, they're doing it the same way using kernel namespacing. So, effectively, you're asking for a way to have containers *nested*. That's a bit odd, unless you have a really good reason to do so. Could you elaborate a bit more on why you want to do this? Because, yeah, by default a container restricts the capabilities in a way that you cannot create new (sub-)namespaces.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a little far fetched. I as basically trying to create a docker cluster, but using containers instead of vm's.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.stgraber.org/2016/04/13/lxd-2-0-docker-in-lxd-712/)

Answer (score 1):

This works on 16.04 now.  See the following q/a for more details:

[What is the workaround for LXD-nested pivileged docker (/dev/.lxc/proc/ error)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907357/what-is-the-workaround-for-lxd-nested-pivileged-docker-dev-lxc-proc-error)

```
lxc launch ubuntu-daily:xenial xenial
lxc config set xenial security.nesting true
lxc exec xenial snap install docker
lxc exec xenial docker run ubuntu ls
```