# What is the workaround for LXD-nested pivileged docker (/dev/.lxc/proc/ error)?

Tags: lxc, docker, lxd

Launching a privileged docker container in an LXD fails with this:

`docker: Error response from daemon: linux runtime spec devices: lstat /dev/.lxc/proc/1482/fdinfo/12: no such file or directory.`

Steps to reproduce:

```
lxc launch ubuntu-daily:16.04 docker -p default -p docker
lxc exec docker -- apt install docker.io -y
lxc exec docker bash
sudo curl -L git.io/scope -o /usr/local/bin/scope
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/scope
scope launch
```

Original guide: [LXD 2.0: Docker in LXD](https://stgraber.org/2016/04/13/lxd-2-0-docker-in-lxd-712/)

Bug report: [Docker containers failing in /dev/.lxc/proc directory #2825 - GitHub](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2825)

How to make it work?

Comment: That guide you linked says you need `A Docker image which behaves when confined by user namespaces, or alternatively make the parent LXD container a privileged container (security.privileged=true)`. Is it possible the issue is with `scope`? Can you run `lxc exec docker -- docker run --detach --name app carinamarina/hello-world-app`, or alternatively, does it work in a privileged container?

Comment: LXD was a privileged container (the 'docker' LXD profile gives `security.privileged=true`). I've tried some `hello-world` image in a privileged LXD - same problem. Don't have this config any more, moved to KVM.

Answer (score 1):

Per Stephane Graber (LXD lead developer) you don’t need the LXD docker profile any more !

See…
https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3299

Comment: Please, try to always provide the version number since when it's fixed. It's always frustrating to clone repos, search for the commit and the next release after it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clean this up a bit, this is [solved quite nicely](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3299) (as @bmullan points out).

16.04, lxd version 2.21, the following sequence works:

```
lxc launch ubuntu-daily:xenial xenial
lxc config set xenial security.nesting true
lxc exec xenial snap install docker
lxc exec xenial docker run ubuntu ls
```

The `docker.io` package, and the `docker` snap both work, but are different versions, and have different update policies, etc.  The snap version used above is 17.06.2-ce, while the docker.io package in xenial is 1.13.1.